# If $A\ B$ are symmetric positive definite matrices then $A>B$ iff $\sqrt{A}>\sqrt{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My guess is, it only holds one way i.e. $A>B$ then $\sqrt{A}>\sqrt{B}$ but not otherwise. Any proof or counterexample would be appreciated.

Comment: Does A > B means , all the element of Mat A > all the element of Mat B ??

Comment: $A>B$ refer to partial ordering of SPD matrices. It implies $A-B$ is positive definite

Comment: Your guess is true.